# Ejecutar un método cada vez que salga de esa Activity

Tags: java, android

Quiero ejecutar un método cada vez que salga de una `Activity`, ya tengo solucionado para cuando salga de la `Activity` mediante el botón *atrás*, pero necesito que también se ejecute si cierras la aplicación desde aplicaciones recientes (estando dentro de esa clase), básicamente que se ejecute siempre que salga de esa `Activity` una vez haya entrado en ella.

Lo que he hecho de momento es esto, que sirve si sales de la `Activity` desde el botón *atrás*

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mireference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("link/Personas");
        Query pendingTasks = mireference.orderByChild("Personas").equalTo(true);
        pendingTasks.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot tasksSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : tasksSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    snapshot.getRef().child("Personas").setValue(false);
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: Es probable que `onDestroy` no se ejecute siempre que pulses el botón atrás. Se ejecuta cuando se destruye (libera de memoria) la `Activity` y esto puede no pasar siempre que des atrás. Usa el método `onBackPressed` en su lugar para asegurar ese caso.

Comment: Vale! Eso también lo había pensado, pero lo que no tengo ni idea de como realizar es ejecutar el método cuando cierre la aplicación desde esa clase, gracias por tu comentario :) @JoseD.Jurado

Comment: No hay forma de detectar ese caso en Android, ya que la aplicación simplemente se mata sin ejecutar ningún callback. En su documentación oficial recomiendan hacer el tipo de tareas que tú pretendes hacer en el método `onPause`. Cita: "you should use the onPause() method to write any persistent data (such as user edits) to storage" - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: [addShutdownHook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook) podría interesarte.

Comment: Pero `addShutdownHook` se ejecutaría desde cualquier `Activity` que esté si no me equivoco, no? O también es posible utilizarlo para que solo se active cerrando la aplicación estando en una `Activity` en concreto? @A.Cedano

Comment: Creo que lo que has comentado "funcionaba" el problema es que firebase deja la función activada hasta que cierras la aplicación, necesito que firebase solo haga la función una sola vez@sioesi

Answer (score 0):

Para esto precisamente usa el método `onDestroy()`, de esta forma al salir de la `Activity` llamarías el método deseado :

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

     //Llama metodo antes de salir.

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Es lo que uso, el problema es que al ir atrás (a `MainActivity`) *Firebase* sigue poniendo en `false` todos los `true`, necesito que cuando salga de esa `Activity` *Firebase* ya no siga haciendo eso. Es decir, que solo haga eso cuando salgo de esa `Activity` y no vuelva a hacerlo hasta que vuelva a salir (una vez haya vuelto a entrar, obviamente) en esa `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar `onActivityResult()`. Cuando lances la activity desde **MainActivity** usa `startAcytivityResult()` y cuando regreses de la activity puedes controlar lo que sucede después de haberla cerrado con `onActivityResult()`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent Data){
    //llama tu método
}
```